# GUID error after I import External Dependencies Manager (EDM) and Firebase Core from Package Manager

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Google Firebase and wanted to do some sample app.
But after import External Dependencies Manager (EDM) and Firebase Core from Package Manager, it gave me GUID errors, example the image below.

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcvWg.png)

I do hope Firebase or Unity3d expert able to help me with this.

I'm using Unity3d 2019.3.13f1 and Firebase SDK 6.14.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have run into an issue similar to [this one](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/console-warnings-for-duplicate-guids-for-plugins-shipped-in-packages). If you installed via a UnityPackage and said "yes" to installing EDM4U:
[image: Screenshot of "Package Manager Resolver" in Unity]

You'll want to double check that you've followed the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#add-sdks-upm).

To summarize:

- EDM4U provides a tool to uninstall managed packages which is accessible using the Assets > External Dependency Manager > Version Handler > Uninstall Managed Packages menu option. Select all Firebase SDKs as well as External Dependency Manager and click Uninstall Selected Packages.
- Alternatively you can also remove the SDK manually from Assets folder.

So if you've installed the package repositories, you'll want to make sure that you remove from your Assets folder:

- Firebase
- Parse
- PlayServicesResolver
- ExternalDependencyManager
- Editor Default Resources/Firebase
- Plugins/Android/Firebase
- Plugins/iOS/Firebase

Alternatively, if Unity Package Manager integration isn't for you, you can remove the installed registries:
[image: Assets/External Dependency Manager/Package Manager Resolver/Remove Registries]

You may want to re-install the Unity Package afterwards as well in case they'd been partially uninstalled.

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but I hope it helps!

--Patrick

Comment: thank you for the quick response, patrick.
appreciated your tutorial videos

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/c9i9DHU

Currently, I having this issue now.

Comment: My guess may have been off, did you integrate with the Unity Package Manager by clicking the "Add Selected Registries" button from that first screenshot? It would also be useful to know your operating system and version.

Comment: Unity3d 2019.3.13f1
Firebase SDK 6.14

Comment: That's exciting, I'll go echo that to the team as a debugging step!